# Script to match names submitted via a form with MySQL database breaks when name contains apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysql-real-escape-string, apostrophe

I have script that enters names into a MySQL database, using mysql_real_escape_string so that apostrophes are handled correctly.  The trouble I am experiencing is with the script below that checks to see if names entered using another form correspond to names already in my database and if names are found updates the row.

When I try to enter a name with an apostrophe into the form processed by this script, I get an error message stating that the name wasn't found, and the name in the error message contains a backslash before the apostrophe, which is obviously the issue.

So the question is, how can I amend the script below so that it will work with names with apostrophes?

Thanks,

Nick

```
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
if ($row_count > 0) {

    mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    $name = array();
    $workshop = array(); 
    $not_found = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
        // variable sanitation...
        $name[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
        $workshop[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);
    }
    $names = "('".implode("','",$name)."')";

    $not_in = Array();

    // lets say all names doesn't exist in `conference`
    foreach($name as $value) {
        // names in array are keys, not values
        $not_in[$value] = true;
    }


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM conference WHERE Name IN $names"); 
    while(list($dbname) = @mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
        // delete those name from $not_in who exists
        unset($not_in[$dbname]);
    }

    // names in $not_in array are keys, not values
    $not_in = array_keys($not_in);

    if(empty($not_in)) {
        // its ok, all names have been found. do the magic.
        for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
            $sql = "UPDATE conference SET Workshop = '$workshop[$i]' WHERE Name LIKE '$name[$i]'";
            mysql_query($sql);
            $body .= "Name: " . $name[$i] . "    Workshop: " . $workshop[$i] . "\n\n";
        }
```

Comment: do you happen to know, what is mysql_real_escape_string for?

Comment: It appends a backslash so that the apostrophe is handled as a string rather than as code

Comment: so, why do you think it is an issue? BTW, any chance you can shorten your code by a factor, say, 5?

Comment: I have shortened code, not by a factor of 5, as I don't want to cut anything out that's relevant.  In the original form, using mysql_real_escape_string does not add a backslash to the entries in my database (only to the email that is generated).  But it is adding backslashes to the values to be compared.  If I remove mysql_real_escape_string from the code above for the name value, there is no backslash in the error message, but the name still can't be found in the database.  So, I'm stuck/confused!

Comment: @Nick: By just reading your code example, I do not see any problems why it should not search names with apostrophes. Are you sure the data is in the right format? Can you please give a snapshot of your data, like output from a SELECT query, to see how does the apostrophe records look? It might also help if you could do `echo "SELECT Name FROM conference WHERE Name IN $names"`

Comment: @Abhay Thanks.  `echo "SELECT Name FROM conference WHERE Name IN $names"` returns for example `('John O\'Shea')`  SELECT queries return the name with apostrophe, in the correct format, e.g. John O'Shea

Comment: Does your PHP have magic_quotes enabled? You could be double-escaping the names because of that. (magic_quotes SHOULD be turned off and taken out back and tortured to death slowly and painfully).

Comment: @Marc B The first thing I did was disable magic_quotes by adding a PHP.ini file with `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` to the same folder as my PHP script.  Prior to this I was seeing three backslashes in the error message.

Comment: Ok. show us a sample record in the database (cut 'n paste the query results), and show us the EXACT query that your code is generating. Showing us a hammer and screwdriver is useless - we need to see whatever you're trying to build with them. And put those in your question. Comments are NOT a good place for extended/formatted code segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm! I think I might have found the issue. The problem might not be with the query but with the PHP code. I'll try to explain below using your example John O'Shea.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
    // variable sanitation...
    $name[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
    $workshop[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);
}
$names = "('".implode("','",$name)."')";

$not_in = Array();

// lets say all names doesn't exist in `conference`
foreach($name as $value) {
    // names in array are keys, not values
    $not_in[$value] = true;
}
```

After the above code, Array $not_in will contain escaped keys because $name already contains values escaped using mysql_real_escape_string(). Hence, for example:

$not_in[John] = true;
$not_in[John O\'Shea] = true;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM conference WHERE Name IN $names"); 
while(list($dbname) = @mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    // delete those name from $not_in who exists
    unset($not_in[$dbname]);
}
```

Now $dbname in the above code contains unescaped values retrieved from the DB, for example John O'Shea without the backslashes. Since this is not what $not_in contains, the unset() will not work. This means that all apostrophe values remain in the $not_in array.

So the fix is to keep unescaped values in $not_in.

Hope this makes sense!

========== EDIT: In response to how to keep unescaped values in $not_in:

The idea is to do escaping just where it is needed. Here are the changes that you may do to your code:

Rewrite the first for() as below:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
    // variable sanitation...
    //$name[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
    $name[$i] = ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]);
    $workshop[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);
}
$names = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode("','",$name)) . "')";
```

And rewrite the UPDATE statement as:

```
$sql = "UPDATE conference SET Workshop = '$workshop[$i]' WHERE Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name[$i]) . "'";
```

By the way, According to your code, the UPDATE will not run if there is one name that does not exist in the database. Is it absolutely necessary to run the UPDATE only if all the $_POST['name'] are found in the database? If not, you can significantly reduce the amount of code.

I haven't tested the above changes but I think they should work. Let me know if you get any issues.

========== EDIT 2: Code snippet for updating records that exist and generating errors for records that did not

Hey Nick, I think only writing the below code should do the trick:

```
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
if ($row_count > 0) {
    mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE conference SET Workshop = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]) . "' WHERE Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]) . "'");
        $affectedRows = mysql_affected_rows();
        if ($affectedRows == 0) {
            echo '<br>Name did not exist - ' . $_POST['name'][$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, but I'm not sure how to keep unescaped values in $not_in.

Comment: Hey @nick, please see the EDIT part in my response above

Comment: Thanks very much Abhay. The above changes seem to be working fine and I have marked the question as answered. If you have any other ideas as to how the script could run more efficiently I'd be glad to hear them. Essentially I just need an error if any of the names in my form are not found in the database. Are you suggesting that, if multiple names are entered on the form and one of them is not found but the others are, the script could update those names that are found, and generate the error for the name that is not, so that only the names that haven't been found need to be re-entered?

Comment: That's great Nick that the changes work for you. And yes, you understood me correct. The script could only update the names that are found and generate errors for those that aren't. I'll shortly post a snippet for it

Comment: Nick, please see EDIT 2 above.